# Beep in headphone when usb-mouse is plugged in or moved

Tags: linux, debian, headphones

I have installed debian (wheezy) on my laptop. Previous OS was ubuntu. I get a beep each time I plug in my (wired) USB mouse and every time I move it. An older wired USB mouse does not have this problem, I can plug it in and move it with no beeping. I also get no beeping when plugging in other USB devices (I tried with a camera).

How can I stop this?

This is the output of `dmesg | tail` after plugging the mouse in:

```
[ 7720.353311] usb 4-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 26
[ 7725.670394] usb 4-1.1: new low-speed USB device number 27 using ehci_hcd
[ 7725.768030] usb 4-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=09da, idProduct=000a
[ 7725.768037] usb 4-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 7725.768041] usb 4-1.1: Product: USB Mouse
[ 7725.768044] usb 4-1.1: Manufacturer: A4Tech
[ 7725.771411] input: A4Tech USB Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.1/4-1.1:1.0/input/input31
[ 7725.771844] a4tech 0003:09DA:000A.0013: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [A4Tech USB Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input0
[ 7728.257145] uvcvideo: Failed to set UVC commit control : -71 (exp. 26).
[ 7728.257160] uvcvideo 1-1.2:1.1: resume error -5
```

P.S.

Beeping mouse model is:
A4Tech X6-6AK. GLaser.

Comment: >Is the sound coming from the mouse or from the headphone? - My mouse is very quit and peaceful. It doesn't move by itself only with my help. It does not bite. :) Sound is coming only from headphones. Laptop speakers keep silence.

Comment: So one wired mouse causes beeps but another wired mouse does not? Connect the mouse that causes beeps and connect a different headphone and see if it stops. What's the mouse? Did you try a different USB port?

Comment: I tried different USB-ports but no results. I can't find another headphones yet.

Comment: This also can be a symptom of having a broken wire in the mouse cable. The disconnect/reconnect beep is caused as the mouse electronics drop offline and get redetected.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you only get this problem with a specific mouse probably means that your system has a problem with that mouse only. We can't really help unless we know the exact model.

A possible workaround would be to disable all beeps (which I do anyway). Depending on which module is used for the beep one of these should remove it:

1. Blacklist the `pcspkr` module.

   First find out if it is loaded and if it is causing the problem:

   ```
   lsmod | grep pcspkr
   ```

   If that command returns nothing, then try one of the other options. If the command does return something, the module is loaded. Try unloading it and then moving the mouse, do you still get the beeps?

   ```
   sudo rmmod pcspkr
   ```

   If that stops the beeps, you can stop `pcspkr` from being loaded by adding it to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`:

   ```
   echo "blacklist pcspkr" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
   ```
2. Mute the `beep` in alsamixer:

   [image]
3. If you are using the `snd_hda_intel` module, add this line to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

   ```
   options snd_hda_intel beep_mode=0
   ```

   Reboot.

Comment: I added mouse model at end of the question.

Comment: > lsmod | grep pcspkr --- return "pcspkr                 12579  0 "

Comment: >sudo rmmod pcspkr --- did not stop the beeping.

Comment: @webprogrammer we try to minimize comments on the SE sites, please post just a single comment with what you want to say and don't break it into many small ones.

Comment: ok, I will try but I don't know how to add new line to my comment. Neither "Enter" nor "Ctrl+Entrl" not working as I was expected. --- I have not installed "alsamixer". In my "/etc/modprobe.d/" there are 2 files: "fbdev-blacklist.conf" and "radeon-kms.conf" should I create new file "alsa-base.conf"?

Comment: To add a new line, just continue writing, you don't need to do anything special. It also sounds like you don't have alsa installed, so creating a new file will not work (it should also not cause any problems so you could try, I just don't expect it to do anything useful). I suggest you post this in a debian forum if you get no more suggestions here.

Comment: >We can't really help unless we know the exact model. - I added model (A4Tech X6-6AK. GLaser.) - Is this helpful? Anyway, thanks for the trying!

Answer (score 0):

Plugging my USB mouse into a rear USB port instead of into a front port (close to my headphone jacks) solved this problem for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. If you'd like to ask a new question, click on the Ask Question button at the top of the page and enter your question. This area is for answers, so your post will likely be deleted shortly.